# Error "write EPIPE" while pushing Heroku PostgreSQL database

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, git-push

An error `write EPIPE` occurred while loading Heroku PostgreSQL database from the local database.

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
heroku pg:push postgres://localhost:5432/design-sa-1 DATABASE_URL --app design-sa
```

[image: screenshot]

Appeared only **recently**, before this was not.

My system Windows 10, local databases v.11 or v.12 - the result is one - this error. I have already tried it on two old applications - the result is one – this error.
The applications themselves (Django 3.0/ Python 3.7) are deployed on Heroku without errors.
Local `python manage.py dumpdata > db.json` works perfect.

Comment: encountered the same issue no response from heroku already created a ticket . 14 hours and yet still unassigned.

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing the tables and heroku push works but adding the tables back again it won't proceed.